# Elasticsearch - boosting fields for multi match without specifying complete field list in query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to boost fields using multi match query without specifying complete field list but I cannot find out how to do it. I am searching through multiple indices on all fields, which I don't know at the run time, but I know which are the important ones.

For example I have index A with the fields 1,2,3,4 and index B with fields 1,5,6,7,8. I need to search across both indexes through all fields with the boosting on field 1.

So far I got

```
GET A,B/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "somethingToSearch"
    }
  }
}
```

Which goes through all fields on both indices, but I would like to have something like this (boosting match on field 1 before the others)

```
GET A,B/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "somethingToSearch",
      "fields" : ["1^5,*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way how to do it without using bool queries?

Comment: why do you use numbers for fields? don't you have some human readable names for them?

Comment: I am not, its just an example. Imagine name, address, description or anything else if you want to :)

Comment: Put real examples, there is no profit from posting "abstract examples"

Comment: OK, so human readable example (I got many indices and hundreds of fields):
Index "bank" - fields: "name", "address". Index
"customer" - fields: "name", "gender", "age".

I want to find all texts with "al", thats OK.

`GET bank,customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "al"
    }
  }
}`

But what if I want to boost name field? How to write it without specifying all fields? Something like this:

`GET bank,customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "al",
      "fields" : ["name^5","*"]
    }
  }
}`